# How to get all the coordinate points (X and Y) in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, draw, uibezierpath

I am writing an app which allows the user to draw what ever they want in the view. While they drawing I am sending the coordinate values simultaneously to web using Json and draw the same diagram in web. When I draw slowly I am getting  all the coordinates values like this.

```
{"XY":["92,240","94,240","96,240","97,240","98,240","99,240","100,240","102,240","103,240","104,240","104,240","105,240","106,240","107,240","108,240","108,240","110,240","110,240","112,240","112,240","114,240","115,240","116,240","117,240","118,240","120,240","120,240","120,240","122,240","122,240","124,240","124,240","126,240"]}
```

But when I draw quickly I am getting the desired drawing but missing lots of coordinate values.

```
{"XY":["96,320","117,302","170,262","252,208"]}
```

The following code that I used to implement this.

```
@implementation PJRSignatureView
{
    UIBezierPath *beizerPath;
    UIImage *incrImage;
    CGPoint points[10];
    uint control;
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [incrImage drawInRect:rect];
    [beizerPath stroke];

    // Set initial color for drawing

    UIColor *fillColor = INITIAL_COLOR;
    [fillColor setFill];
    UIColor *strokeColor = INITIAL_COLOR;
    [strokeColor setStroke];
    [beizerPath stroke];

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ([lblSignature superview]){
        [lblSignature removeFromSuperview];
    }
    rectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    control = 0;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    points[0] = [touch locationInView:self];

    CGPoint startPoint = points[0];
    CGPoint endPoint   = CGPointMake(startPoint.x + 1.5, startPoint.y
                              + 2);



   [beizerPath moveToPoint:startPoint];
        NSLog(@"myPoint = %@", [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:endPoint]);
        NSLog(@"beizerPath    :%@",beizerPath);
    [beizerPath addLineToPoint:endPoint];
     NSLog(@"beizerPath end:%@",beizerPath);
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    control++;
    points[control] = touchPoint;

    if (control == 4)
    {
        points[3] = CGPointMake((points[2].x + points[4].x)/2.0, (points[2].y + points[4].y)/2.0);

        [beizerPath moveToPoint:points[0]];
        [beizerPath addCurveToPoint:points[3] controlPoint1:points[1] controlPoint2:points[2]];

        [self setNeedsDisplay];

        points[0] = points[3];
        points[1] = points[4];
        control = 1;
    }
       NSLog(@"beizerPathmove:%@",beizerPath);
    NSString *rect_xy = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f,%.f",touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y];

    [rectArray addObject:rect_xy];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self drawBitmapImage];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    [beizerPath removeAllPoints];

    NSMutableDictionary *rectDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [rectDict setValue:rectArray forKey:@"XY"];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:rectDict options:0 error:nil];

    // Checking the format
    NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    control = 0;
}
```

How to find all the coordinate values even when I draw quickly?

Comment: It might be your code that is slowing down the touch handlers and therefore missing events.  Start by removing the creation of `jsonData` in `touchesEnded` and seeing if that improves things.

Comment: @trojanfoe even i tried json data outside of the touchesEnded but getting the same kind of results. And I NSLog the string value rect_xy  even on there coordinate are missing.

Comment: Used NSLog for the string "rect_xy"  Even before adding array called "rectArray" coordinates are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apple products sends the touch events at a certain intervals. So, If you draw/write anything slowly its possible to get all of the coordinate values, if you draw/write fast you will less some of them. And apply the same kind of function in the web that you have used. Hope this will be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The system sends touch events at a certain interval. If you move slow you get more, but going fast you get less of them. You can't get more if you move fast. But you also don't need more probably. You just have to draw the line between points, no matter if the distance between them is small or bigger.

Comment: is there any way to control system touch events at a certain interval?

Comment: No. You can't change the interval at which the system is sending touch events. But why do you need more? Maybe there's another solution for your problem.

Comment: Actually the app is about to show the MQTT Server speed to the user. So the user draws anything it should be shown in webpage if i get the all the coordinates so that it will be worked. if the coordinate values missed just the dotted only showing in the web.

Comment: Well, the same as you do on iOS, you have to do on web: - draw a line between points, not just draw the points.